# How to install Quake 3

Tags: software-installation, software-center, games

I downloaded Quake 3 from the Ubuntu Software Center, and it said I have to use game-data-packager with the original files to not play the demo version. I have the pak0.pk3 from the full game, but I don't know what to do, they didn't provide instructions on how to do it. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also installed Quake 3 from the Ubuntu Repository and managed to get the full game running *successfully*. You will need to install both the Quake 3 package as well as the application `game-data-packager` to create a *non-distributable* Quake 3 data package. First run the following command from a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt install quake3 game-data-packager innoextract
```

Now move the vital `pak0.pk3` file to the location of your choice. After a bit of experimentation I created `~/.q3a/baseq3` and moved the file there. Another reasonable and perhaps more traditional location for this file would be `/usr/share/games/quake3-data/baseq3/` but the location in $HOME worked well enough for me and I illustrate the required syntax here:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ mkdir -pv ~/.q3a/baseq3
mkdir: created directory '/home/andrew/.q3a/baseq3'
andrew@corinth:~$ cp -v pak0.pk3 ~/.q3a/baseq3
'pak0.pk3' -> '/home/andrew/.q3a/baseq3/pak0.pk3'
andrew@corinth:~$
```

Make sure the path to *your* file `pak0.pk3` is correct or you will get an error message of 'File not found...'. Now tell the `game-data-packager` application to sort out the data files:

```
game-data-packager -i quake3 ~/.q3a/baseq3/pak0.pk3
```

After some considerable downloading and repackaging you can now start fragging!!! Obligatory screenshot below:

[image]

Works well on my system and hopefully on yours as well...

Comment: Haven't been on this forum in a while, and honestly not interested in trying to get this game to work right now. I'll just mark your answer as correct, as it probably is. Thanks regardless!

Comment: @Matthew Well, thanks for coming back to the question anyway :) I have been playing ut2400 lately so I might use my own answer to play this game too...